# iOS - does registerForRemoteNotificationTypes need to always be executed?

Tags: ios, push-notification

in an iOS appliation, to receive push notifications, the application needs to register for it like this:

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

The first time this happens, iOS asks the user for permission.

My question is, if this line of code needs to be executed each time the application launches, or if it only needs to be executed a single time and in subsequent executions of the app it does not need to register anymore and still can receive notifications?

Comment: Documentation gives clear answer to this question. Read section "Registering For Remote Notifications" carefully. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yes you have to, read this below from Apple Developer Library:
```

"Your app needs to reregister every time it is launched—in iOS by calling the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method of UIApplication, and in OS X by calling the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method of NSApplication."

For more information on Local and Remote Notification go to [Local and Push Notifications by Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2/%22Local%20and%20Push%20Notifications%22)

Comment: what is the reason for this? does something stop working if it does not register upon subsequent launches?

Comment: device token can change, this is the reason behind executing remote notification registration code.